# Not able to add additional column to the sink `Azure Data Explorer` in the Copy Activity of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to add an additional column to the Azure Data Explorer sink from the source Blob Storage using the "Additional columns" in the Copy Activity "Source" tab, but I am getting the following error:

"Additional columns are not supported for your sink dataset, please create a new dataset to enable additional columns."

When I changed the sink dataset to a blob storage, it works fine and an additional column gets created. Is there anything I am missing on here when I using the Azure Data Explorer as sink?

Alternatively, how can I add an additional column to the Azure Data Explorer table as a sink?

Comment: If the my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Columns**

As per official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy) - This feature works with the latest dataset model. If you don't see this option from the UI, try creating a new dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ADX sink doesn't support altering the table using Copy activity.
To add a column to the ADX table, use `.alter-merge table` command in advance and map the additional column to the target column under the Mapping tab of the Copy activity.
[.alter-merge table command](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-merge-table-command)